# Convert a nested list into a data frame safely, where some values are singular and some are vectors

Tags: r, purrr

I have a list in which each element in itself is a named list of attributes, the sort of output you would get from a typical JSON:

```
l <- list(
  list(
    "attr1" = 1,
    "attr2" = "x",
    "attr3" = 3:4
  ),
  list(
    "attr1" = 5,
    "attr2" = "y",
    "attr3" = 7:9
  ),
  list(
    "attr1" = 10,
    "attr2" = "z",
    "attr3" = 12
  )
)
```

Some of the attributes have a **single** value of the same type (e.g. `attr1` and `attr2`), and some are vectors themselves, of varying length (e.g. `attr3`).

I would like to use `purrr` to convert this list into a data frame, where `attr1` and `attr2` are "regular" columns, and `attr3` is a **list** column:

```
tibble(
  attr1 = c(1, 5, 10),
  attr2 = c("x", "y", "z"),
  attr3 = list(c(3:4), c(7:9), 12)
)
```

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  attr1 attr2 attr3    
  <dbl> <chr> <list>   
1     1 x     <int [2]>
2     5 y     <int [3]>
3    10 z     <dbl [1]>
```

**The catch is, I have many attributes, and I have no idea which are singular and which are lists**

This simple approach would of course fail because of `attr3`:

```
attrs <- names(l[[1]])

get_element_details <- function(element, attrs) {
  element_list <- map(attrs, function(attr) pluck(element, attr))
  names(element_list) <- attrs
  element_list
}

df <- l %>% map_dfr(get_element_details, attrs)
```

> Error: Argument 3 must be length 1, not 2

This approach works, but I have to know in advance which attributes are expected to be singular and which lists. I'm using a named vector `attrs_dict`, sort of like a Python dictionary, which a `pluck_wrapper` function consults in order to return a singular value or a list:

```
attrs_dict <- c("attr1" = FALSE, "attr2" = FALSE, "attr3" = TRUE)
pluck_wrapper <- function(element, attr, attrs_dict) {
  res <- pluck(element, attr)
  if (attrs_dict[attr]) {
    return(list(res))
  }
  return(res)
}
get_element_details <- function(element, attrs_dict) {
  attrs <- names(attrs_dict)
  element_list <- map(attrs, function(attr) pluck_wrapper(element, attr, attrs_dict))
  names(element_list) <- attrs
  element_list
}
df <- l %>% map_dfr(get_element_details, attrs_dict)
df
```

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  attr1 attr2 attr3    
  <dbl> <chr> <list>   
1     1 x     <int [2]>
2     5 y     <int [3]>
3    10 z     <dbl [1]>
```

Alas, as said, what do I do if I have many attributes, and I do not know in advance which are singular and which are lists? (it's safe to assume all of them exist though)

I can of course always return `list(pluck(...))` but this would get me:

```
get_element_details <- function(element, attrs) {
  element_list <- map(attrs, function(attr) list(pluck(element, attr)))
  names(element_list) <- attrs
  element_list
}

df <- l %>% map_dfr(get_element_details, attrs)
df
```

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  attr1     attr2     attr3    
  <list>    <list>    <list>   
1 <dbl [1]> <chr [1]> <int [2]>
2 <dbl [1]> <chr [1]> <int [3]>
3 <dbl [1]> <chr [1]> <dbl [1]>
```

Which I have no idea how to simplify (easily) but this would also be a good direction.

Comment: Wouldn't it be helpful if you have one observation as 1 row meaning first two rows will be `1 x 3` and `1 x 4` ? Or you want them as lists only?

Comment: @RonakShah do you mean that the resulting data frame would be unnested? (In this case 2 + 3+ 1 = 6 rows in total)

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: The issue I see is that many attributes of type list, of length much more that 1 or 2 or 3, can unnest to something very ugly... but your answer below is amazing thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check length of each element in the list and if all of them are 1, we can `unlist` them.

```
library(purrr)
transpose(l) %>% map_dfc(~if(all(lengths(.x) ==1)) unlist(.x) else .x)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  attr1 attr2 attr3    
#  <dbl> <chr> <list>   
#1     1 x     <int [2]>
#2     5 y     <int [3]>
#3    10 z     <dbl [1]>
```

If you would like to have complete data unnested, you could do

```
transpose(l) %>% map_dfc(list) %>% tidyr::unnest(cols = V1:V3)

# A tibble: 6 x 3
#     V1 V2       V3
#  <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
#1     1 x         3
#2     1 x         4
#3     5 y         7
#4     5 y         8
#5     5 y         9
#6    10 z        12
```

Comment: this no longer works in latest `purrr`. But this does: `transpose(l) %>% map_dfc(~if(all(lengths(.x) ==1)) unlist(.x) else tibble(.x))` except for not keeping the column's name which I'm not sure how to do. Also, it would only work for a *single* list column.

Answer (score 1):

In base R you may use `cbind`.

```
res <- do.call(rbind, lapply(l, function(x) data.frame(t(cbind(x)))))

res
#    attr1 attr2   attr3
# x      1     x    3, 4
# x1     5     y 7, 8, 9
# x2    10     z      12

str(res)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ attr1:List of 3
  ..$ : num 1
  ..$ : num 5
  ..$ : num 10
 $ attr2:List of 3
  ..$ : chr "x"
  ..$ : chr "y"
  ..$ : chr "z"
 $ attr3:List of 3
  ..$ : int  3 4
  ..$ : int  7 8 9
  ..$ : num 12
```